# Run query in TFS from another server without visual studio installed

Tags: tfs

I try run `query take details` from TFS but i get this error

"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TFSWebService.WorkItemQuery.GetWorkItemForReleaseState()"

I add this DLL to my bin

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll
```

but still same error

NOTE: need to fixed without install visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install a small package. Download and more Information:

[Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Object Model Installer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa)

[Stand-alone installer for TFS object model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/22/stand-alone-installer-for-tfs-object-model.aspx)